# Problem adding features to shapefile

Tags: qgis

As of yesterday I can no longer create new features in shapefiles that were previously working fine. There's no error messages, I can go through the process of adding a feature as normal but it just doesn't create it - in either the map or attribute table. Any solutions?

qgis v2.18.3

Comment: can you try remove all plugins and restart Qgis,If the problem persists ,reinstall Qgis

Comment: Your `avoid intersection` in the snapping option is ON, by any chance?